# Как оптимизировать конкатенацию строк в Java?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

```
public static String getCommaSeparated(List<Long> list)
{
    String s = "";
    for (Long v : list)
    {
        if (s.length() > 0) s += ", ";
        s += v;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Оптимизировать по чему? Я бы предложил держать булеву переменную вместо length() на каждой итерации цикла...

Comment: String s = list.toString(); return s.substring(1, s.length() - 1) выведет абсолютно такой же результат

Comment: Без сабстринга там будет в начале [ и в конце ]

Comment: @AndrewBystrov точно, забыл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для конкатенации в цикле надо бы использовать `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String delim = "";

for (Long aLong : list) {
    sb.append(delim).append(aLong);
    delim = ", ";
}

return sb;
```

для Java 8, можно использовать [Collectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

```
return list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Вместо `Object::toString` можно лямбду применить `el -> el.toString()` (по вкусу), т.е:

```
return list.stream().map(el -> el.toString()).collect(joining(", "));
```

где для `joining` произведен импорт `java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;`

Comment: А почему лямбду лучше применить, чем ссылку на метод?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Ну это конечно мое имхо. нагляднее показывается, что происходит. Но наверное это по вкусу. Убрал "даже лучше", чтоб не смущало

Comment: Просто такую конструкцию el -> el.toString() мне идейка подсказывает менять на ::toString и я уже на автомате так пишу)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov ну не все, что она там предлагает изменить - это есть хорошо)) Но как бы то ни было, наверное дело вкусовщины. Хотя может есть какая-то миллиметровая разница в скорости. Но этого я не знаю, честно говоря.

Answer (score 1):

Речь идёт о конкатенации строк в java.

Оптимизация будет выглядеть так:

```
public static String getCommaSeparated(List<Long> list)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long v : list)
        {
            if (builder.length() > 0) builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(v);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Подробнее можно почитать, например, здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/260767/

Comment: Не стоит изобретать велосипед. Посмотрите реализацию метода toString() в классе java.util.AbstractCollection. Там будет почти тоже самое, за исключением, что там будут добавляться [ и ] в начало и конец соответственно

Comment: @AndrewBystrov ну так тут причём тут велосипеды. Спросили про конкретный метод - вот его оптимизация. То что тут написано почти то же самое что и в java.util.AbstractCollection::toString() только подтверждает, что оптимизация правильна.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov таким образом в итоге получаем тоже самое + задачу удалить [ в начале и ] в конце. Хорошая оптимизация. Так держать!

Answer (score 1):

Для задачи разделения списка в строку разделенным каким нибудь знаком можно использовать метод `StringUtils.join(list, ",");` из библиотеки `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` который возвращает нужный String

Comment: Дело в том, что там не строки, а `Long`. Я тоже в начале недоглядел....А так будет ClassCastException `cannot be cast to java.lang.String`  ..... и запятую надо в двойные кавычки записать

Comment: На счет счет кавычек да, а вот на счет ClassCastException - нет, внутри этого метода вызывается toString, и Long без проблем пролезет в этом методе